# Button didnt disable inside the form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

greeting developers. i am doing project for university related to Javascript. i create one page got button add and unfriend button which is disable.once user click add button the prompt box appear and after they click Ok for promp, the unfriend button will able to click while add button become disable. if click unfriend, add button will able to click. i don't know how explain it. may be read my question can be headache. sorry for that. my problem is button does not disable,if i never put inside form it work but since i put inside form doesnt work. guys is there any solution please help me

```js
 function myFunction(add){
     var subject = prompt("Please enter Subject that want to study");
     if (subject != null){
      document.getElementById("subject").value = subject;
      
     document.getElementById("btn").disabled=false;
     document.getElementById("add").disabled=true;
     document.getElementById("add").value="request sent";
     
     }
    }
    function disableButton(btn){
      
        
      document.getElementById("add").disabled=false;
      document.getElementById("btn").disabled=true;
     document.getElementById("add").value="Add friend";
     form.submit();
    }
```

```html
<form method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off"  > 
    <input type="submit" value="unfriend" id="btn" onClick="disableButton(btn)" disabled/>  
    <input type="hidden" id="subject" name="subject"/>
    <input type="submit" value="add" id="add"  onclick="myFunction(add)"  /></form>
```

Comment: I tested it in my local ... it seems to be working as expected

Comment: nope the unfriend button not enable to click after press add button ..

Answer (score 1):

The "add" and "unfriend" buttons both submit a POST request which is refreshing the page since there is no form action specified. Perhaps you need to read up on HTTP methods. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp is a good resource.

If your plan is to add a server side page to handle the request at a later time you can temporarily add the following to the form tag `onsubmit="return false"`.

If you simply want to use the form inputs without submitting the form you should remove `form.submit()` from the disableButton function and change the types of the add and unfriend buttons from `type="submit"` to `type="button"`. You can also remove the method and enctype of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don’t really use forms unless its more than 3 fields.

Two things to think about:

You got the right written idea, you are however missing event.preventDefault(), which will make your website refresh itself, which will then force out everything to refresh.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

The other is that try between the both buttons as they are both  i suggest one myfunction to be onclick in a button tag.  just to avoid two inputs types.

Additional:
I suggest you add jquery to make things easier with the toggle function.